# A variation on the math.SE logo: does it have mathematical content?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics

As explained very nicely in a [meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13409/214353), our logo is based on the Penrose triangle:

[image]

Here is a modification which is somehow more symmetric:

[image]

Can this version be similarly related to some known geometric object like Penrose triangle or something?